# Keep screen off when power supply is connected/disconnected

Tags: android, android-rom

A rooted device I use, namely HTC 10 running stock Android 8 firmware, has annoying behavior: when power supply is connected/disconnected, its screen goes on for about 15 seconds.

I know it for sure that other devices (even different models from HTC itself) could keep screen off in this situation. So I don't think it's a HTC 10 specific issue and I guess the behavior depends on some (hidden?) OS settings.

Also, LineageOS has an option for controlling this in its Settings.

Could someone (probably, experienced in ROM development) point me to a location of system flag(s) controlling whether the screen goes on when power supply is connected/disconnected?

Comment: Just FYI this is normal Android behavior.  Occurs on every device I've ever had.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you. I understand that could be the default AOSP behavior nowadays. But as I mentioned in the question, I know models with stock firmware which don't do this.